# Need To Hide A Designer-Only Property From PropertyGrid For A .NET Winforms Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, design-surface

I am deep into using the Winforms designer (System.ComponentModel.Design namespace) in my C#/.NET solution so that my users have access to a form designer within my running application. Much of it works well, but I ran into a very specific problem: I encountered a property on a Microsoft control that appears only during design-time--i.e., for the design-time instance of the control. I want to suppress that property so that users cannot modify it when they place an instance of that control on my program's implementation of the Winform design surface.

Details: When a user drag-and-drops a control from the toolbox to the designer surface, I ensure that the newly added designer instance of the control is selected (so that it present resize handles and so the property grid displays that control's design-time properties). I bind the selected objects on the designer surface to the property grid by using the selection service's **GetSelectedComponents()** method and assigning the property grid's **SelectedObjects** property to the result.

Many of the controls on my toolbox are .NET controls. One of them is the .NET Winforms **TableLayoutPanel** control. When you place an instance of that control on a designer surface, you will see a **Columns** property in the bound **PropertyGrid**. I would like to suppress that property so that it doesn't appear in the **PropertyGrid**.

The issue is that this Columns property doesn't appear to exist in the properties list for the **TableLayoutPanel** type--so using `selectedComponents[0].GetType().GetProperties()`, for example, doesn't contain a **Columns** property. Also, I cannot create a new or override for the existing **Columns** property because it doesn't appear as an exposed property for the **TableLayoutPanel** control at design time--thus I cannot decorate it with the `Browsable(false)` attribute.

I can't seem to leverage `PreFilterProperties` or `PostFilterProperties` because I can't interact and customize the **TableLayoutPanel's** designer.

How can I suppress the **Columns** designer property for the **TableLayoutPanel** so that it doesn't appear in the **PropertyGrid** without having to write my own designer?

Comment: The property name is `ColumnStyles` if it helps. `Columns` is its display name.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think of that and I'm surprised that Microsoft decided to expose ColumnStyles as a property name other than ColumnStyles (I wonder why they did that?) Is the only way I could have discovered this would have been to browse the .NET source and look for the display name attribute for the ColumnStyles property?

Comment: PropertyGrid always shows the display name which is set by `DisplayName` attribute for a property. It's just for display purpose in PropertyGrid, DataGridView or any other component/framework which uses that attribue. When you press F12 or go to definition of a member, VS shows its attributes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to avoid writing `TableLayoutPanelDesigner` yourself, then here is a workaround that I can suggest.

[`ITypeDescriptorFilterService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.itypedescriptorfilterservice?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) is the interface which is responsible for calling [`PreFilterProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner.prefilterproperties?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method of the designer. The [`DesignSurface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.designsurface?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) class has a an instance of an implementation of this interface registered in its `ServiceContainer`. So you can remove the existing registered instance and register a new instance of your own implementation of `ITypeDescriptorFilterService`.

In the new implementation, override `FilterProperties` and do whatever you think is suitable, for example you can check if the type of the component is `TableLayoutPanel`, then don't call its designer `PreFilterProperties`.

Then to wrap up the solution, you need to create your own design surface by deriving from `DesignSurface` class and removing the registered `ITypeDescriptorFilterService` and registering the desired instance which you created.

**Example**

Just for your information, the name of the property which you are looking for is `ColumnStyles` and it has `Browsable(false)` attribute by default. But the default designer of `TableLayoutPanel` replaces this property with a browsable version.

What I've done in this example is stopping the designer from making those properties Visible.

First provide a custom implementation of `ITypeDescriptorFilterService`. The following one is in fact the existing implementation in `System.Design` assembly which I've changed its `FilterProperties` method and checked if the component is `TableLayoutPanel`, I've asked to do nothing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class TypeDescriptorFilterService : ITypeDescriptorFilterService
{
    internal TypeDescriptorFilterService()
    {
    }

    private IDesigner GetDesigner(IComponent component)
    {
        ISite site = component.Site;
        if (site != null)
        {
            IDesignerHost service = site.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
            if (service != null)
                return service.GetDesigner(component);
        }
        return (IDesigner)null;
    }

    bool ITypeDescriptorFilterService.FilterAttributes(IComponent component, IDictionary attributes)
    {
        if (component == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("component");
        if (attributes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("attributes");
        IDesigner designer = this.GetDesigner(component);
        if (designer is IDesignerFilter)
        {
            ((IDesignerFilter)designer).PreFilterAttributes(attributes);
            ((IDesignerFilter)designer).PostFilterAttributes(attributes);
        }
        return designer != null;
    }

    bool ITypeDescriptorFilterService.FilterEvents(IComponent component, IDictionary events)
    {
        if (component == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("component");
        if (events == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("events");
        IDesigner designer = this.GetDesigner(component);
        if (designer is IDesignerFilter)
        {
            ((IDesignerFilter)designer).PreFilterEvents(events);
            ((IDesignerFilter)designer).PostFilterEvents(events);
        }
        return designer != null;
    }

    bool ITypeDescriptorFilterService.FilterProperties(IComponent component, IDictionary properties)
    {
        if (component == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("component");
        if (properties == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("properties");
        if (typeof(TableLayoutPanel).IsAssignableFrom(component.GetType()))
            return true;
        IDesigner designer = this.GetDesigner(component);
        if (designer is IDesignerFilter)
        {
            ((IDesignerFilter)designer).PreFilterProperties(properties);
            ((IDesignerFilter)designer).PostFilterProperties(properties);
        }
        return designer != null;
    }
}
```

Then create a design surface by deriving from `DesignSurface`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyDesignSurface : DesignSurface
{
    public MyDesignSurface() : base()
    {
        this.ServiceContainer.RemoveService(typeof(ITypeDescriptorFilterService));
        this.ServiceContainer.AddService(typeof(ITypeDescriptorFilterService), new TypeDescriptorFilterService());
    }
}
```

Then for example initialize the design surface this way:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var surface = new MyDesignSurface();
        var host = (IDesignerHost)surface.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        var selectionService = (ISelectionService)surface.GetService(typeof(ISelectionService));
        surface.BeginLoad(typeof(Form));
        var root = (Form)host.RootComponent;
        var tableLayoutPanel1 = (Control)host.CreateComponent(typeof(TableLayoutPanel), "tableLayoutPanel1");
        root.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
        var view = (Control)surface.View;
        view.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(view);
        selectionService.SetSelectedComponents(new[] { tableLayoutPanel1 });
        var propertyGrid1 = new PropertyGrid() { Dock = DockStyle.Right, Width = 200 };
        this.Controls.Add(propertyGrid1);
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObjects = selectionService.GetSelectedComponents().Cast<object>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then run your designer application and you will see `Columns` and `Rows` properties are hidden as expected.

You need to hide `ColumnCount` and `RowCount` properties and also the verbs assigned to editing/adding/removing columns and rows.

Comment: Reza, awesome answer (as always from you)--one that I'll accept as correct for now while I spend a little bit of time digesting and implementing what you've suggested.

Comment: Reza, I've had time to get to this (apologies for the delay): I have FilterProperties properly hooked, but I don't see in your example above how the TableLayoutPanel Columns and Rows properties are hidden. Where is that done?

Comment: No problem at all. Look at this piece of code in `FilterProperties`: `if (typeof(TableLayoutPanel).IsAssignableFrom(component.GetType())) return true;` It means do not run `PreFilterProperties` or `PostFilterProperties` of `IDesigner`. But why do we may want to do this? Because the property which you are looking for is `ColumnStyles` and it has `Browsable(false)` attribute by default. But the default designer of `TableLayoutPanel` replaces this property with a browsable version in `PreFilterProperties` method of the `TableLayoutDesigner`.

Comment: I thank you--I am going to post a related follow-up question shortly.

Comment: I see that logic now (wow--that wasn't obvious until you explained further). Thank you again. I have a follow-up question posted now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841974/need-to-hide-a-designer-only-property-from-propertygrid-for-a-net-winforms-cont